# r error occurs in statement with else but not in if statement

Tags: r, if-statement

My data set contains numeric values with decimals

When I write a simple if statement like this:

```
data$Segment <- ifelse(data$RankAll> 10,'Gekko',0)
```

I do not get an error but when I write it like this:

```
data$Segment <- if (data$RankAll<4) 'Moore' else if 
                   (data$RankAll<6) 'Marvin' else if
                   (data$RankAll<8)'Branes' else if 
                   (data$RankAll<10) 'Fox' else 'Gekko'
```

It returns the error:

```
Warning messages:
 1: In if (data$RankAll < 4) "Moore" else if (data$RankAll < 6) "Marvin" else if (data$RankAll <  :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (data$RankAll < 6) "Marvin" else if (data$RankAll < 8) "Branes" else if (data$RankAll <  :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
 3: In if (data$RankAll < 8) "Branes" else if (data$RankAll < 10) "Fox" else "Gekko" :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
 4: In if (data$RankAll < 10) "Fox" else "Gekko" :
```

the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `ifelse()` is vectorized, but `if()` isn't.  You can use something like: `ifelse(data$RankAll<4, 'Moore', ifelse(data$RankAll<6, 'Marvin', ifelse(data$RankAll<8, 'Branes', ifelse(data$RankAll<10,'Fox', 'Gekko'))))`

Comment: ROCK!  that was exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See SamDickson's approach in the comment above for an approach that keeps the same logic as the original.

To do the same thing with DRYer code:

```
data$Segment <- cut(data$RankAll, breaks = c(0, 4, 6, 8, 10, 100), right = FALSE)
levels(data$Segment) <- c('Moore', 'Marvin', 'Branes', 'Fox', 'Gekko')
```